# How to check if two URL's lead to the same path?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a URL Shortener, and I've decided to recyle the short ID's if possible to save space in my database. How can i check if 2 URL's lead to the same path?

For example, let's say a user generates a short URL for `https://google.com/`.

My app generates the following short id: `jkU3`

So if this user visits `https://tiny.url/jkU3` my express server will redirect the visitor to `https://google.com/`.

This works like a charm, but know let's imagine another person visits `https://tiny.url/` and generates a short URL for `https://google.com`. And another one comes and generates a short URL for `https://www.google.com/`, and another one comes and generates one for `https://www.google.com`. You get the point..

So far my app would have wasted 4 short ID's.

How can i prevent this from happening? Is there a regex for this?

This is the current code I have for generating short URL's:

```
app.post("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const shortUrl: string = nanoid(4);
  const destination: string = req.body.destination;

  UrlSchema.create({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    origin: shortUrl,
    destination: destination,
  }).then(() => {
    // Unique Id
    res.json(shortUrl);
  });
});
```

Comment: Though it may seems like a waste of short ID's in the case of google, do note there are some websites that works `www` and some works without. Some website works with the last `/` but some works without, *and* if the system admin doesn't do the job well, they may forget to do correct redirection for pages with and without `/`. There are also cases webpage may work with http/https and you cannot you work with only one protocol. So all in all, other than setting all urls to the same upper or lower casing, I don't advise you to make any changes to them. Because there's no guarantee

Comment: and more often than not, users will copy/paste the long url to your tiny url rather than manually typing them. Hence, the chance of different variation of the same url is very minimal, unless you create script to fetch those url, and check for the 302 redirections and get the final url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've listed four slightly different URLs:

```
https://www.google.com
https://google.com
https://www.google.com/
https://google.com/
```

None of these are technically the same https request, though it sounds like you want to assume that the `/` at the end is optional and thus does not make it a different target URL.

The last two are not guaranteed to be the same host as the first two.  For `google.com` and `www.google.com`, they are the same host, but this is not guaranteed to be the case for all possible hosts.

If you want to assume that these four are all to the same host no matter what the domain is, then you just have to normalize the URL before you put it in your database and then before assigning a new shortened ID, you search the database for the normalized version of the URL.

In this case, you would remove the `www.` and remove any trailing slash to create the normalized version of the URL.

```
function normalizeUrl(url) {
    // remove "www." if at first part of hostname
    // remove trailing slash
    return url.replace(/\/\/www\./, "//").replace(/\/$/, "");
}
```

Once you've normalized the URL, you search for the normalized URL in your database.  If you find it, you use the existing shortener for it.  If you don't find it, you add the normalized version to your database with a newly generated shortId.

Here's a demo:

```js
function normalizeUrl(url) {
    // remove "www." if at first part of hostname
    // remove trailing slash
    return url.replace(/\/\/www\./i, "//").replace(/\/$/, "");
}

const testUrls = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://google.com",
    "https://google.com/",
];

for (const url of testUrls) {
    console.log(normalizeUrl(url));
}
```

FYI, since hostnames in DNS are not case sensitive, you may also want to force the hostname to lower case to normalize it.  Path names or query parameters could be case sensitive (sometimes they are and sometime they are not).

To include the host case sensitivity normalization, you could use this:

```js
function normalizeUrl(url) {
    // remove "www." if at first part of hostname
    // remove trailing slash
    // lowercase host name
    return newUrl = url.replace(/\/\/www\./i, "//").replace(/\/$/, "").replace(/\/\/([^/]+)/, function(match, p1) {
        // console.log(match, p1);
        return "//" + p1.toLowerCase();
    });
}

const testUrls = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://google.com",
    "https://google.com/",
    "https://WWW.google.com",
    "https://www.Google.com/",
    "https://GOOGLE.com",
    "https://google.COM/",
    "https://www.Google.com/xxx",     // this should be unique
    "https://google.COM/XXX",         // this should be unique
];

for (const url of testUrls) {
    console.log(normalizeUrl(url));
}
```

Comment: removing www in normalize function is you assuming that www.example.com and example.com will lead to the same url, though in reality, there is no guarantee that domain with and without www leads to the same page, and there are websites that don't even resolve www

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - That caveat is fully explained in the answer.  It's up to the OP if they want to make that assumption or not.  I personally would not.  Their question indicated they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating a new entry you can check work destination with

```
const existing = await UrlSchema.findOne({destination:req.body.destination});
if(!existing){
    // create new
} else{
    // return same
}
```

This way you will be creating destination if it does not exist already. You can remove tariling slash(/) if it exists to match URLs better,